# losing session storage data after reopen the browser

Tags: angularjs, html, session

after execute the function the session created in browser. and i close and open the same browser the session will cleared.

```
$scope.logIn = function () {        
        $http(
            {
                method: 'post',
                url: 'Service.asmx/fn_CheckLogin',
                data: $.param({ strMob: $scope.login.mob, strPwd: $scope.login.pwd }),
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {                               
                    sessionStorage.user = data[0].UserName;                
                    sessionStorage.loggedIn = true;                                
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                sessionStorage.user = '';                  
                    sessionStorage.loggedIn = false;    

            });
    };
```

Comment: That is how session storage works. If you want the data to remain even after you close the browser, use localStorage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: @Nannakuhtum thanks for the support . i am new in web app. is the following code i get some website and is it possible to work the following code on document load     `if (sessionStorage.loggedIn) {
        $scope.ngLogin = sessionStorage.user;
        $scope.loggedIn = sessionStorage.loggedIn;
        $('#divUser').show();
        $('#divLoginNav').hide();
    }
    else {
        $scope.loggedIn = false;
        $('#divUser').hide();
        $('#divLoginNav').show();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Use $localStorage.
Here is the link: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Comment: thank u. How to do. A user login a website and close the browser without logout. again he open the same browser how to detect login. ?? i am new in web app and i am using html,angular js and asp.net(VB)

Comment: if you store anything in $localStorage, will not go anywhere even if yu close browser. ex: $localStorage.userKey = "key"
it will be stored in browser, you can use it in your app

Comment: go through the github url, its all explained there

Answer (score 0):

Answer to comment added by OP.

Yes, it is possible to execute code on document ready in your angular controller.

Append following event in you base( main) controller:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
   // code you need to execute on document ready
});
```

**Session Storage:**

> Data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores. **Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated**, which differs from how session cookies work.

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Edit (answer to Op's comment on this answer):

To maintain information even after user closes browser, You need to user `localStorage`.

Google it, it is similar to sessionStorage in usage and is easy to understand. Found this [codepen](https://codepen.io/octowombat/pen/eyngH) to help you maybe. Still read about it and only then use it.

Also if you are open for discussion, I will suggest you to store just the username in `localStorage` and not a flag like logedIn instead maintain this information on server . Then whenever user closes browser on one system and logs in from other system and logs out. He will be logged out from all systems he has used. This is accepted behavior for most of the web applications.

Comment: thank u. How to do. A user login a website and close the browser without logout. again he open the same browser how to detect login. ?? i am new in web app and i am using html,angular js and asp.net(VB)

Comment: can u give me a description about session_start(); in php