# How can I make clicked elements highlight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, local-storage

I'm trying to make seen posts highlight. Here is a simplified demo of my codes:

```js
$('li').on('click', function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','pink');
  return false;
});
```

```css
li{
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover{
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href='#1'>first post</a></li>
  <li><a href='#2'>second post</a></li>
  <li><a href='#3'>third post</a></li>
</ul>
```

As you see, it sets a pink background color to clicked post. Now I need to store it into localstorage. Something like this:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','pink');

  // storing into localstorage
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
      localStorage.seen = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  }

  return false;
});
```

---

**Ok, what's my question?**

How can I check localstorage and then set that pink background color to the element? *(when the browser is closed and opened again)*. As you know, after a while, `localStorage.seen` will be containing lots of post's links. So how should I search in it?

Anyway, how can I implement a mechanism to handle such a thing?

Comment: _localStorage.seen_ will contains only last clicked anchor href(single string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7hww5116/

***CSS:***

```
li{
  cursor: pointer;
}

 li:hover{
    background-color: #eee;
 }
```

***HTML:***

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#1'>first post</a></li>
  <li><a href='#2'>second post</a></li>
  <li><a href='#3'>third post</a></li>
</ul>
```

***JS:***

```
var seen = [];
$('li').on('click', function(){
$(this).css('background-color','pink');
// storing into localstorage
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if(!seen.includes($(this).find('a').attr('href'))){
        seen.push($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
        // Set to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('seen', JSON.stringify(seen));
    }
  }
});

var seenAlready = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('seen'));
$.each(seenAlready,function(index, value){
   $("a[href="+'"'+value+'"'+"]").parent().css('background-color','pink');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage stores key-value pairs`. So to store a entire javascript object we need to serialize it first (with JSON.stringify, for example):

```
localStorage.setItem('color', JSON.stringify(color));
```

`stringify` means, take an object and return its presentation as a `string`

Then to retrieve it from the store and convert to an object again:

```
var color = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('color'));
```

If we need to delete all entries of the store we can simply do:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the color in `localStorage` using `localStorage.setItem()` only if it does not exist and add the color only if exists using `localStorage.getItem()` to get the color:

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  var color = localStorage.getItem('color');
  if (color === null) {
    localStorage.setItem('color', $(this).find('a').attr('href'));
  } else {
    $(this).find('a').css('background-color', 'pink');
  }
  return false;
});
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href='#1'>first post</a></li>
  <li><a href='#2'>second post</a></li>
  <li><a href='#3'>third post</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can (should) css this:

> **:visited** is a pseudo-class selector that can change some of the styling on an anchor link (a) element if the user's browser has already visited the link. It's meant to help users distinguish the difference between links they have and haven't visited.

```
a:visited{
    color: pink;
}
```

This will do as you want, style the anchor when a user visited an url. Will be remembered untill history is cleared (which would alse clear all localStorage solutions anyway).
You should go for this, instead of a custom solution, as this behaviour is common behaviour to users, where your own solutions might differ and confuse.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/v/visited/

Answer (score 0):

If you see this answer and the comments you will get an idea about the issue you are facing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37496814/1174865

instead of localStorage.seen you need to use custom array to store application specific data.

like

localStorage.setItem('visited', $(this).find('a').attr('href'));

Answer (score 0):

First get the relative link on which you have clicked and then try to save it in `localstorage.setItem()` and get stored value by `localStorage.getItem()`.

Try Below Script,Hope this will work as you have mentioned.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul li a').on('click', function (e) {
            localStorage.setItem('color', $(e.target).attr('href'));
        });
        var activeLink = localStorage.getItem('color');
        if (activeTab) {
            $('ul li a[href="' + activeLink + '"]').css('background-color', 'pink');
        }
    });
```

```css
li{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    li:hover{
        background-color: #eee;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href='#1'>first post</a></li>
    <li><a href='#2'>second post</a></li>
    <li><a href='#3'>third post</a></li>
</ul>
```